# Orientability of algebraic manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

Is algebraic manifold always orientable?

For example, unorientable Mobius strip $M$ can be represented as
$$x(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2}\right)\cos u$$
$$y(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos\frac{u}{2}\right)\sin u$$
$$z(u,v)= \frac{v}{2}\sin \frac{u}{2}$$
Hence there exists algebraic equation $Z(x, y, z) = 0$ : $(a, b, c) \in M \Rightarrow Z(a, b, c) = 0$. But fact that $M$ is equal to set of all solutions of $Z$ is not obvious, even if it is true.

Comment: This is not an "algebraic manifold", this is just the parametrization of the Mobius band.

Answer (score 3):

Algebraic means given by *polynomial* equations. Over $\Bbb C$, yes, it'll be orientable. Not true over $\Bbb R$: The hyperplane section of $\Bbb RP^3$ (given by a linear equation) is $\Bbb RP^2$, which is not orientable.

Comment: Even more: Every smooth closed manifold is diffeomorphic to some real algebraic subset of $R^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Thanks, @studiosus. A nontrivial result, that. :)

Comment: Thanks,@TedShifrin, but can you please briefly explain why it is always orientable over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The smooth points (which form a connected open subset) make a complex manifold, and complex manifolds are always (canonically) orientable. This can be seen because of the Cauchy-Riemann equations on chart overlaps or by realizing that for any choice $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of basis for the complex tangent space, $v_1,iv_1,v_2,iv_2,\dots,v_n,iv_n$ gives a basis for the real tangent space and you can easily check that any two such give the same orientation.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, it is, mostly due to John Nash!